# Mocking TableClient DeleteEntityAsync - Azure.Response

Tags: azure, unit-testing, moq, azure-table-storage

I need to mock the `DeleteEntityAsync` method of `TableClient`.
[TableClient.DeleteEntityAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.deleteentityasync?view=azure-dotnet)

My current implementation uses an *empty* Response object.

```cs
var mockResponse = new Mock<Azure.Response>();
Mock<TableClient> tableClient = new Mock<TableClient>();
tableClient.Setup(_ => _.DeleteEntityAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Azure.ETag>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(mockResponse.Object));
```

How can I set `Content` and `StatusCode` in the mock? At the moment no values are assigned.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on the same thing. Try this:

```
var mockResponse = new Mock<Response>();
mockResponse.SetupGet(x => x.Status).Returns((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
mockResponse.SetupGet(x => x.Content).Returns(BinaryData.FromString("data source here"));

tableClient.Setup(x => x.DeleteEntityAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), default, default)).ReturnsAsync(mockResponse.Object);
```